# Vuetify v-app can't apply class attribute

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't apply `class="grey lighten-4"` to v-app tag.
Even color attribute is not working

```html
<template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4"> 
    <Navbar />
    <v-content class="mx-4">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

I want to make the content have the "grey lighten-4" color, see screenshot:
[image: I want to make the content have the "grey lighten-4" color]

Comment: Looks like its working (look at your navbar), what is an expected outcome?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a noob and had that same problem too. It worked for me when I applied the class to `v-main`. It's not showing any errors now.

```
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-main class="blue-grey lighten-4">
          <Navbar />
          <router-view></router-view>
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
    </template>
```

PS: It's my first day on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to move everything in `v-content` tag and then change the `v-content` class, like below :

```
<template>
  <v-app>

    <v-content class="grey lighten-4">
      <Navbar />
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <v-app> 
    <v-container fluid class="grey lighten-4">
      <Navbar />
      <v-content class="mx-4">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: But the height of the container is not 100%

Answer (score 0):

in App.vue use style

```
<style scoped>
.theme--light.v-application {
    background: #F5F5F5;
}
</style>
```